# How to find out the amount of time for which a key is being pressed in c++?

Tags: c++

I am creating a game that involves projectile motion for my school project. I want to get the input for angle values by determining how long a certain key is being pressed. The code should then give an angle value equivalent to the amount of time the key was pressed. Any suggestions or ideas ?

Comment: Which library are you using to access keyboard? How are you keeping record of time? What did you try so far? Show us the code!

Comment: This is 100% platform or framework dependent. We'll need more information. Usually you'd listen for the keydown event and then timestamp that. Then listen for the keyup event and timestamp that and subtract the two.

Comment: Here's one algorithm:  Let the OS notify you when a key is pressed.  Start a count-up timer.  Stop the timer when the OS notifies you that the key is released.  Read the timer.  This is not portable and requires OS API.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no point in even using a timer when timestamps will do.

Comment: @Mgetz: It's another method.  It's roots are in embedded systems, where there may not be a timestamp.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews fair but the OP did say a school project rather than an embedded school project 

Comment: Another algorithm, more portable:  Input from the keyboard, having the user hold down the key for character repeat.  Count the characters and multiply by some duration factor.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to get the status of the keys in a non blocking way.

There is no way to achieve this in the standard c++ library, so you need to make use of some kind of library/framework, of which there are plenty.

If you are using windows, one way to do it is to interface directly with the OS API that gets you directly key events from your application from the windows queue.

This is a small example in which the application waits three seconds, then prints the key events that happened in those three seconds along with the [key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) that generated the event.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#define MAX_INPUT_EVENTS 100

int main()
{
    //Handle to console input buffer
    HANDLE g_console_handle;
    //Return dword
    DWORD ret, ret_aux;
    //Input event structure
    INPUT_RECORD input_event[ MAX_INPUT_EVENTS ];
    //return flag
    bool f_ret;


    std::cout << "press some keys while the process waits 3 seconds...\n";

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(3000) );

    //get handle to console
    g_console_handle = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );

    //Get number of pending input events
    f_ret = GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents( g_console_handle, &ret );
    //if: fail
    if (f_ret == false)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERR: could not get number of pending input events\n";
        return true; //Fail
    }
    //if: at least one event has been detected
    if (ret > 0)
    {
        //if: above processing limits
        if (ret >= MAX_INPUT_EVENTS)
        {
            std::cerr << "ERR: too many input events\n";
            return true; //Fail
        }
        //Get all the input event
        f_ret = ReadConsoleInput
        (
            g_console_handle,
            input_event,
            ret,
            &ret_aux
        );
        //for: every input event
        for (DWORD t = 0;t < ret_aux; t++)
        {
            //switch: Decode event type
            switch(input_event[t].EventType)
            {
                //case: keyboard
                case KEY_EVENT:
                {
                    //Structure holding key event
                    KEY_EVENT_RECORD &event = input_event[t].Event.KeyEvent;
                    //List of virtual keys
                    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
                    //true=down, pressed
                    if (event.bKeyDown == true)
                    {
                        std::cout << "Virtual key: " << event.wVirtualKeyCode << " is down\n";
                    }
                    //false = up, released
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << "Virtual key: " << event.wVirtualKeyCode << " is up\n";
                    }

                    break;
                }
                //unhandled input event
                default:
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }   //end switch: Decode event type
        }   //end for: every input event
    }   //end if: at least one event has been detected
    //if: no event detected
    else
    {

    }
}
```

This is the output, a list

```
press some keys while the process waits 3 seconds...
Virtual key: 68 is down
Virtual key: 65 is down
Virtual key: 68 is up
Virtual key: 65 is up
Virtual key: 68 is down
Virtual key: 68 is up
Virtual key: 65 is down
Virtual key: 70 is down
Virtual key: 87 is down
Virtual key: 70 is up
Virtual key: 65 is up
Virtual key: 70 is down
Virtual key: 87 is up
Virtual key: 70 is up

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.046 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The way to use the key detection depends on how you made your game loop. If a jitter of a few tens of milliseconds is acceptable, you can just add timestamp detection inside the loop without worrying too much.